# set.seed() and .Random.Seed() in R

Tags: r, random, simulation

I am taking a simulation class and I am having trouble understanding .Random.seed in R. I understand that we use set.seed() so that simulations are reproducible and it is essentially the initial value of our PRNG. Could someone explain to me what .Random.seed does and why is it important? (e.g. when would I use it).

Comment: I do not have your explanation, but the documentation page says not to use it. `.Random.seed is an integer vector, containing the random number generator (RNG) state for random number generation in R. It can be saved and restored, but should not be altered by the user`

Comment: `.Random.seed` object is created as a result of `set.seed()`. Try `set.seed(1L)`;   `ls(all.names = TRUE)`